# Does Colmap still support non-nvidia GPU support?

Tags: macos, gpu

**Describe the bug**
Colmap feature extractor doesn't recognize the cuda devices on my machine since I pulled the latest repo.

```
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @        0x11303b349  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @        0x11303e9ef  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @        0x11303bc77  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @        0x10d99e10d  colmap::SiftFeatureExtractor::SiftFeatureExtractor()
    @        0x10d7bcd19  RunFeatureExtractor()
    @        0x10d7da01c  main
[1]    38034 abort      colmap feature_extractor --database_path  --image_path   RADIAL  1  1
```

**To Reproduce**

I ran Colmap feature extractor

```
colmap feature_extractor --database_path DATABASE_PATH --image_path IMAGES_PATH --ImageReader.camera_model RADIAL --ImageReader.single_camera_per_folder 1 --SiftExtraction.use_gpu 1
```

**Desktop (please complete the following information):**

- OS : macOS Mojave version 10.14.6
- Colmap branch: dev
- Colmap commit: ad7bd93

**Additional context**
When I was using Colmap version from August 30th commit, I didn't have this issue
I tried to go back to that commit but the build is failing so I am kinda stuck

Comment: https://github.com/colmap/colmap/releases

Comment: I tried to build a previous version but the build crashed : ```error: no template named 'enable_if_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'boost::enable_if_t'?
inline std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename K::Rep_tag, Cartesian_tag>::value, std::size_t>
```